# Plant recommendations for tropical food forest shrub layer

Tags: permaculture

This is a small area in the front yard in Jakarta.  What I have right now are three mango trees providing a rather dense and low canopy.  This is bordered to the south with the house and a fence/wall runs through it forming an effective boundary to the North.  Along the North and West we have lime and Jackfruit trees.  To the east things open up a bit and there is a Papaya tree which is tall enough.

There isn't much direct light at this point reaching in (I am considering pruning back the mangos a bit after the harvest) but this will change as the papayas get just a little taller too, so I am looking for shrubs I can plant between the papaya and the mangos.

For a food forest, what are the main recommendations? I can tell you there is insufficient sunlight for cassava to do well at present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pigeon pea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeon_pea) (*Cajanus cajan*) or [Moringa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moringa_oleifera), depending on what you want. Both plants will fix nitrogen and provide nutrient-dense edibles; they are perfect for chop and drop mulching too.

Comment: Aloe can also be eaten, and can grow as a crop.

Comment: Is Morniga a nitrogen fixer? Moringa belongs to Moringaceae family. Does any family other than Fabaceae fixes nitrogen?